# Cannot use object of type ... as array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am using an API from themoviedb.org, which is returning an array:

```
array:20 [▼
  0 => TVShow {#186 ▼
    -_data: array:13 [▼
      "original_name" => "Star Trek: Discovery"
      "id" => 67198
      "name" => "Star Trek: Discovery"
      "vote_count" => 48
      "vote_average" => 6.3
      "poster_path" => "/ihvG9dCEnVU3gmMUftTkRICNdJf.jpg"
      "first_air_date" => "2017-09-24"
      "popularity" => 75.562899
      "genre_ids" => array:1 [▶]
      "original_language" => "en"
      "backdrop_path" => "/s3kVP6R3LbJvvoPnDQEcJNEH2d0.jpg"
      "overview" => "Ten years before Kirk, Spock, and the Enterprise there was Discovery.  Star Trek, one of the most iconic and influential global television franchises, returns 5 ▶"
      "origin_country" => array:1 [▶]
    ]
  }
  1 => TVShow {#187 ▶}
  2 => TVShow {#193 ▶}
  3 => TVShow {#194 ▶}
  4 => TVShow {#195 ▶}
  5 => TVShow {#196 ▶}
]
```

I am trying access it like I normally would an array:

```
foreach($array as $item {
  echo $item["original_name"];
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> "Cannot use object of type TVShow as array"

Could someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: TVShow `TVShow {}` looks like its an object.

Comment: It occurs because TVShow items are objects. Try to access to the "-_data" attribute from TVShow, and then to access the data through the array keys

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I think so too, what's the next step? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: The next step is finding out what kind of object it is and what public methods it has.

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez - thats a good idea to try, but my bet is `_data` preceded with an underline is not public property, That is the convention I use at least.  non public is prefixed with an underline, it's not "standard" but I think it's fairly common.

Comment: @SuperOcean - I would look in the API's documentation that you are using.  Without knowing exactly the PHP api you are using or how you are using it, I would be just guessing.

Comment: Its a few levels deeper then where you are first off, and there is an object in the way.  At best it would be `$item->_data['original_name']` but I would bet that data is not a public property so you cant access it outside of the class, which means the class probably has a method like `$item->getOriginalName()` or `$item->get('original_name')` or `$item->getData('original_name')`  but like I said you should refer to the api.  ( my examples are just what is typically used in these cases )

Comment: see `TVShow` is an Object that contains an array named `_data` that contains what you want.  As I said without more info on the API, I'm just guessing.

Comment: @ ArtisticPhoenix Thank you so much. The answer was indeed in the API Wrapper documentation! Issue solved. (I was looking in the API documentation, but no in the PHP wrapper docs).

Comment: Could you post a short answer on it.  You can answer your own questions. That way somone seeing it later will know what it was.  Or delete the question, its bad form to leave them unanswered.  I am not worried about any points for helping, I just gave some standard advice.  Glad I could point you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question with lot's of handholding from **@ArtisticPhoenix**.

I am using [TMDB PHP API](https://github.com/php-tmdb/api) wrapper. In order to access the "original_name" value, I needed to do this:

```
echo $item->getName();
```

As detailed in the wrapper [documentation](https://code.octal.es/php/tmdb-api/class-TVShow.html).